# Trying to understand why nested switch case statement is not compiling

Tags: java

So I'm trying to figure out why my IDE is not accepting this piece of code. The error it's giving me is that the return statement is missing. But after doing some digging I found out that when I already have a return statement I don't really need a break. Heres me code.

The month, day, and year are private variables that have already been initialized in the private constructor. Each of the switch cases is supposed to take the date inputs and out the date in a specific format.

```
public String toString(int format) {
  switch (format) {
    case 1:
      return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    case 2:
      String pattern = "00";
      DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
      return decimalFormat.format(month) + "/" +
        decimalFormat.format(day) + "/" +
        year;
    case 3:
      String abbrev = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
      return abbrev.substring(month * 3 - 3, month * 3 - 1) +
        "/" + day + "/" + year;
    case 4:
      switch (month) {
        case 1:
          return "January" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 2:
          return "February" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 3:
          return "March" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 4:
          return "April" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 5:
          return "May" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 6:
          return "June" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 7:
          return "July" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 8:
          return "August" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 9:
          return "September" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 10:
          return "October" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 11:
          return "November" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        case 12:
          return "December" + " " + day + ", " + year;
        default:
          System.out.println("Error please try again");
          break;
      }
      default:
        System.out.println("Error please try again");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is supposed to return a String.

This means: *any* path that leads to the "exit" of your method, needs to return a value.

```
default:
  System.out.println("Error please try again");
```

Does not return a value. It prints a message.

In other words: your two default cases should either return a string, such as `"invalid input"`. But in the real world, this isn't what you want.

Your code seems to be about some sort of Date class. And your `toString(int)` implementation allows for *invalid* data. That is where your problem starts! You should **validate** your fields at some point. But that point is *not* when you are asked to format it. If you do it at that point, that method should rather throw an exception to indicate: "can't do my work because of bad data".

So, two choices: either your code validates all user inputs when the user provides them (and refuses bad data), or your `toString()` method should throw an exception on invalid data.

Comment: Ohh wow okay that worked...I feel stupid. Yeah I think I had to just directly return the string.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that. Please see the updates I just made.

Comment: I just read your feedback. I actually do have other constructors that validate my data and store the date that has been input. This method essential is just supposed to grab the stored date and then based on the users request of 1,2,3 or 4 will get the output in a specific format.

Comment: Case 4 may still not return a string if month is <1 or >12, (eg: it just logs).  Also, last default may fall through and also not return a String.  I forget whether this is an error or warning condition but either way null, empty string or throwing an exception is prob. your  desired return value.

Comment: @MurtazaMohsin The problem with using int values is exactly that: it is wrong. You should rather use enums for example. Also note: instead of doing a switch to *map* numbers to strings, you could simple use a `Map<Integer, String> monthNamesByNumber` for example. You fill that once upfront, and then you dont need to *switch* later on, but simply go into that map. Saves you plenty lines of code.